# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.'

Tags: c#

Please see the code below:

```
[TestFixture]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            DateTime dob = new DateTime(2001, 02, 29);
            DateTime todaysDate = new DateTime(2001, 02, 29);
        }
    }
```

When I run this code the second line of the method throws an exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.'.  However, if I comment out the first line of the method it runs successfully.  What is the problem?

Comment: Because February in 2001 did not have 29 days.

Comment: comment out the first line still breaks on my machine. unless you meant [TestFixture] which might just skip the Test depending on what [TestFixture] is.

Comment: Good chances are you see an exception on the wrong line. Try adding some code between the first and second line (say, a nice little `for` loop that does nothing for a few iterations), and see what would happen.

Comment: The test fails in both cases on my side too

Comment: @ dasblinkenlight, if I put some code in between then it fails as expected.  Not sure what is going on.  I am running it in Debug mode.

Comment: What test framework are you using? Are you sure it runs the test when you comment out the first line?

Comment: Either call will fail - you can verify by commenting out one or the other.  The curious bit is that the stack trace points to the *second* line when the exception is thrown from the *first* line.

Answer (score 6):

Because in 2001 February had only 28 days not 29 :-)

Comment: Why does the first line run then (when there are two lines).

Comment: Oh my! I didn't notice that!

Answer (score 2):

In case you stumble across this post with a similar confusion about dates - I have found that if you have two date assignments one after the other, and the first one has a problem, the exception may be thrown on the second one (which doesn't have a problem).

See my screenshot below - the first line is bad, but the exception is thrown on the second line.

[image]